# Images will not expand horizontally only and starts a new row? How to change this?

Tags: css

(The code I am trying to edit is hosted on tumblr.com by the way. I would like for my content to expand horizontally (to the right) infinitely-as-needed as images are placed into the text box.

I’ve tried inserting various codes given by my searches on this website/other sites, and a couple such as the `.column` section seem to be one step closer to what I would like.

I have a (permalink?) page with entries in them naturally lined in two rows, like:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
9

...and in the CSS from the main:

```
#container {
position: center;
margin-top: 80px;
z-index: 950;
{block:IfGridTheme}margin-left: 430px;{/block:IfGridTheme}
{block:IfNotGridTheme}margin-left: 435px;{/block:IfNotGridTheme}
}

.entry {
position: justify;
{block:PermalinkPage}width: 8000px;
margin-top: 15px;{/block:PermalinkPage}
word-wrap: break-word;
margin-top: 45px;
}

.column {
float: left;
width: 11%;
padding: 1px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
```

the width: `8000px;` under `.entry` determines the horizontal length of the page and it's just short enough so that 9 falls into a second row. The `width: 11%` under `.column` does something similar; it's determining the spacing between each image so that if i brought it to like 100% it would just be one long column of entries going down and no rows.

I don't want that. I wouldn't like for the width of a row to be anything specific; I would just like one and only one row where I can insert as many pictures as I like at a set height, that has the ability to infinitely extend to the right

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

and not suddenly wrap onto a new row. What should I add/change in my CSS?

edit: in addition from a previous thing I wrote, a lot of the similar questions I browse appear to come up with a solution like `flex-wrap: nowrap`. It (vaguely) appears to be what I'm looking for when websites explain it. But Tumblr does not seem to recognize that property at all, as in it does not highlight when I enter it in the CSS. Why is this, and is there an alternative?